# Fatal Python error: initfsencoding: Unable to get the locale encoding File "/cm/shared/apps/anaconda2/4.5.12/lib/python2.7/encodings/__init__.py"

Tags: python, slurm

I am writing a job submission script for SLURM workload manager. First, I have loaded anaconda2/4.5.12 (including python 2.7) module. Then, I have created conda environment with Python3.7 version. I try to submit the script using "sbatsh" command, but I get this error:

```
Fatal Python error: initfsencoding: Unable to get the locale encoding
File "/cm/shared/apps/anaconda2/4.5.12/lib/python2.7/encodings/__init__.py", line 123
raise CodecRegistryError,\
                        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
Current thread 0x00002aaaaaaffc00 (most recent call first):
/cm/local/apps/slurm/var/spool/job04287/slurm_script: line 19: 40032 
Aborted                 python3 taxo.TXT
```

This is my script file:

```
#!/bin/bash
#
#SBATCH --job-name=taxjob
#SBATCH --nodes=4

#SBATCH --tasks-per-node=3
#SBATCH --time=0-03:00:00
#SBATCH --partition=shortq 
#SBATCH --mem=24GB 
#SBATCH --output=/home/s.e/tax/Ftest-%j.out
#SBATCH --error=/home/s.e/tax/Ftest-%j.err
module load anaconda2/4.5.12
source activate py37
python3  taxo.TXT
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After many tries, the solution was to add the instruction "unset PYTHONPATH" to my script file as follows:

```
....    
module load anaconda2/4.5.12
source activate py37
unset PYTHONPATH
python3  taxo.TXT
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the `"/cm/shared/apps/anaconda2/4.5.12/lib/python2.7/encodings/__init__.py"` if a python2 file, like you can see at the path, but it is trying to be interpreted as a python3 file. You can either fix this conda problem and run it using python2.7 or edit the `encodings/__init__.py` file to make it python3-interpretable

To understand the problem you can try to run this line in python2 and python3 manually:

```
#Python3
>>> raise Exception,\
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    raise Exception,\
                   ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

but

```
#Python2.7
>>> raise Exception,\
...
```

Python3 analog of `raise Exception,\ "str"` is `raise Exception("str")`. So you can change the 123rd line of the file, but it's not a good idea, because other problems may occur, so it's better to fix something in configs/executing commands of anaconda

Comment: If you decide to edit the file, you have to replace lines 123 to 125 with `raise CodecRegistryError('module "%s" (%s) failed to register' % (mod.__name__, mod.__file__))`

Comment: Thank you for answering, I am not able to modify the file because only the administrator of the HPC can edit shared modules such as anaconda2/4.5.12

Comment: I can't use Python2.7 as well, because I am using some packages which are available only for python version > 3.x

Comment: Then, I guess, you have to switch to the `encodings` library for python3

Comment: How can I do it, please?

Comment: Try something like
`conda install python=3.7;
conda create --name py2 python=2.7;
conda create --name py3 python=3.7;
source activate py3 #if Linux/macOS;
activate py3 #if windows`

Comment: https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/user-guide/tasks/switch-environment/